# Problem with Choice-field column when Allow Fill-In is active

Tags: sharepoint-online, online

I can't seem to change the initial value of a Choice field when the Allow Fill-In option is enabled.
I'm using the modern template for SharePoint online 
It is only an issue with Allow Fill-In, I've tried multiple browsers and a different tenant but the issue remains. Is there any workaround? Do you have the same problem?

I've made a gif showing my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx0cE.jpg 
[image]

Comment: What kind of fields are 'Flera; and 'en till'?  Are they 'cascading lookup' fields?  These are fields that have a dependency.  It could be that the combination you are choosing does not exist, according to the dependency, and so it will not allow you to select this combination.

Comment: Hi! They are simple Choice fields that are not connected in any way. The properties for 'Flera': https://imgur.com/a/vvNaDMn -
The only difference between the columns is Allow Fill-In. I can edit 'en till' column but not the other :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, discovered it last week (9th May 18). I couldn't find a solution, including rebuilding my document library from scratch, so I removed allow fill-in, and create an extra option 'other'.

Another option is to create a second list with the options you need and create a lookup field to that list. End-users can add to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting, simply type the new choice option in the field.